# mod_rewrite rules in httpd.conf not working

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, httpd.conf

I am trying to add my rewrite rules to `httpd.conf` and disable `.htaccess` in order to improve server performance. For some reason everything I have tried doesn't work.

in my main `httpd.conf` I have disabled all instances of `AllowOverride` setting them to none.

I have an include file for each site within its virtual host block

```
Include "etc/apache2/conf.d/site.com/rewrite.conf"
```

then in `rewrite.conf` I have something like this:

```
 <Directory "/home/shopmobilephones/public_html">
 RewriteEngine On
 ServerSignature off
 # HTTP > HTTPS #########################################################################
 RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
 RewriteRule (.*) https://shopmobilephones.co.uk%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^/www.shopmobilephones.co.uk [NC]
 RewriteRule (.*) https://shopmobilephones.co.uk%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} libwww-perl.* 
 RewriteRule .* ? [F,L]

 RewriteRule ^/mobiles/deals/cash-back /cashback.php [L]
 RewriteRule ^/mobiles/deals/cheap-mobile-phones /cheapmobilephones.php [L]
 RewriteRule ^/mobiles/deals/clearance-deals /clearance.php [L]
 RewriteRule ^/mobiles/deals/contracts /contractphones.php [L]
 RewriteRule ^/mobiles/deals/12-months-free-line-rental /12month.php [L]
 RewriteRule ^/mobiles/deals/top-deals /dailydeals.php [L]
 RewriteRule ^/mobiles/deals/free-phones /freephones.php [L]
 RewriteRule ^/mobiles/deals/new-mobile-phones /ladeals.php [L]
 RewriteRule ^/mobiles/deals/sim-free-phones /simfree.php [L]
 RewriteRule ^/mobiles/colours/(.*) /colours.php?colour=$1 [L]
 RewriteRule ^/mobiles/(.*)/contract-deals /dealsnew.php?slug=$1&deal-type=1&device-type=Phone&network=all [L]
 RewriteRule ^/mobiles/(.*)/upgrades /dealsnew.php?slug=$1&deal-type=2&device-type=Phone&network=all [L]
 RewriteRule ^/mobiles/(.*)/contract-deals/(.*) /dealsnew.php?slug=$1&deal-type=1&device-type=Phone&NETWORK=$2 [L]

 </Directory>

 <IfModule mod_expires.c>
 ExpiresActive On
 ExpiresByType image/jpg "access plus 1 year"
 ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 year"
 ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 year"
 ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 year"
 ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 1 month"
 ExpiresByType application/pdf "access plus 1 month"
 ExpiresByType text/x-javascript "access plus 1 month"
 ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access plus 1 month"
 ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 1 year"
 ExpiresDefault "access plus 2 days"
 </IfModule>

 # php -- BEGIN cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
 # Set the “ea-php56” package as the default “PHP” programming language.
 <IfModule mime_module>
  AddType application/x-httpd-ea-php56 .php .php5 .phtml
 </IfModule>
 # php -- END cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
```

I have tried adding RewriteBase / and removing all prefixing / this doesn't work I have also taken the rules out of the directory blocks this doesn't work, I have even added the rules in the main httpd.conf inside and out of directory blocks but nothing works, where am I going wrong?

Comment: What is the Apache version?

Comment: The claim "nothing works" is a very general and broad one, I doubt that is literally true. Please be more specific what _exactly_ does not work. Best is to give specific (anonymized) request URLs, your expectation and the actual outcome. Add such details to the question please, not in comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside the http servers host configuration you need to keep the leading slash in path notations, a `RewriteBase` does not make any sense and the rules need to be placed outside some `<Directory>` or `<Location>` section. You have to remove the leading slash in the `RewriteCond` testing the `%{HTTP_HOST}`, but you have to escape the dot characters in there. It seems some current versions of the apache http server do *not* always define the `%{HTTPS}` variable as claimed in the documentation, you can test for the port instead:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
  ServerName example.com
  ServerAlias www.example.com
  ServerAdmin webmaster@example.com
  # ...
  ServerSignature off
  DocumentRoot "/home/shopmobilephones/public_html"

  RewriteEngine On
  # HTTP > HTTPS & www host
  RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443$
  RewriteRule ^ https://shopmobilephones.co.uk%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301]
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.shopmobilephones\.co\.uk$
  RewriteRule ^ https://shopmobilephones.co.uk%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301]
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} libwww-perl.* 
  RewriteRule .* ? [F,L]

  RewriteRule ^/mobiles/deals/cash-back /cashback.php [L]
  RewriteRule ^/mobiles/deals/cheap-mobile-phones /cheapmobilephones.php [L]
  RewriteRule ^/mobiles/deals/clearance-deals /clearance.php [L]
  RewriteRule ^/mobiles/deals/contracts /contractphones.php [L]
  RewriteRule ^/mobiles/deals/12-months-free-line-rental /12month.php [L]
  RewriteRule ^/mobiles/deals/top-deals /dailydeals.php [L]
  RewriteRule ^/mobiles/deals/free-phones /freephones.php [L]
  RewriteRule ^/mobiles/deals/new-mobile-phones /ladeals.php [L]
  RewriteRule ^/mobiles/deals/sim-free-phones /simfree.php [L]
  RewriteRule ^/mobiles/colours/(.*) /colours.php?colour=$1 [L]
  RewriteRule ^/mobiles/(.*)/contract-deals /dealsnew.php?slug=$1&deal-type=1&device-type=Phone&network=all [L]
  RewriteRule ^/mobiles/(.*)/upgrades /dealsnew.php?slug=$1&deal-type=2&device-type=Phone&network=all [L]
  RewriteRule ^/mobiles/(.*)/contract-deals/(.*) /dealsnew.php?slug=$1&deal-type=1&device-type=Phone&NETWORK=$2 [L]

  <Directory "/home/shopmobilephones/public_html">
    # .....
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

If you operate a recent version of the apache http server you probably also want to replace the `[L]` flag with the `[END]` flag which typically increases performance slightly since it prevents an additional loop through the rewriting engine when there is no need for that.

You can move the rewriting rules into a separate file as you suggest in your question, that is fine, just include it where the rules are placed inline in the example above.

Comment: Thanks forgetting that the site ran on :443 I stupidly did not put the custom include file in the VirtualHost block only for the block on port 80 that was the issue but your helped me a great deal thank you.